# How to remove all files from directory without removing directory in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to remove all files from a directory without removing a directory itself using Node.js?
I want to remove temporary files. I am not any good with filesystems yet.

I have found [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/remove) method, which will remove files and the directory. In that, something like `/path/to/directory/*` won't work.

I don't really know what commands should use. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to use wildcards, check out https://www.npmjs.org/package/glob.

Comment: just look up the api, whats so hard in it ? you have to get the files in a directory and then delete them.

Answer (score 288, accepted):

To remove all files from a directory, first you need to list all files in the directory using `fs.readdir`, then you can use `fs.unlink` to remove each file. Also `fs.readdir` will give just the file names, you need to concat with the directory name to get the full path. If your folder have other folders inside, you will need to check for it and use `fs.rmdir` instead.

Here is an example

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const directory = "test";

fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  for (const file of files) {
    fs.unlink(path.join(directory, file), (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  }
});
```

Using promises

```js
import fs from "node:fs/promises";
import path from "node:path";

const directory = "test";

for (const file of await fs.readdir(directory)) {
  await fs.unlink(path.join(directory, file));
}
```

Comment: this works great, and most will already have fs and path required so thats a bonus, no extra packages needed. i just swapped out 'test' for path.join(__dirname, '../../public/uploads')

Comment: to add 2p., the snippet is great and only one thing to keep in mind is that it is async and in scripting/automation cases you might want to use synchronous version of it, the `fs.readdirSync`. Just assign all files: `const files = fs.readdirSync(directory);` and loop same way `for (const file of files) {`.

Comment: How to exclude the folder _".git"_ in the _"test"_ directory?

Comment: You could add an if statement in the for loop to remove that case, but if you want to recursively remove files and folders, you may want to use some npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra

Comment: Note: The recursive flag in fs.promises.rmdir is deprecated and will throw errors in the future.

Comment: "Setting recursive to true results in behavior similar to the Unix command rm -rf: an error will not be raised for paths that do not exist, and paths that represent files will be deleted. The permissive behavior of the recursive option is deprecated, ENOTDIR and ENOENT will be thrown in the future." It looks like the "permissive behavior" is deprecated, not the flag itself.

Comment: The second suggested answer removes the directory even though the original question specifically asked to preserve the directory.

Comment: I changed to sync version and failed with `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Temp\trace-web-call\src'`. And I changed to `unlinkSync` to `rmSync` and succeeded.

Answer (score 116):

Yes, there is a module [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra). There is a method `.emptyDir()` inside this module which does the job. Here is an example:

```
// NON-ES6 EXAMPLE
const fsExtra = require('fs-extra');
fsExtra.emptyDirSync(fileDir);

// ES6 EXAMPLE
import * as fsExtra from "fs-extra";
fsExtra.emptyDirSync(fileDir);
```

There is also an asynchronous version of this module too. Anyone can check out the link.

Comment: Very useful module, you should try it out, there are plenty of funciotions you will love for sure.

Comment: Yes, why implementing something that is not trivial.

Comment: Just a little warning, this way has slightly different behavior than the question's desired behavior, because the `emptyDir` function creates the directory if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 54):

It can also be done with a synchronous one-liner without dependencies:

```
const { readdirSync, rmSync } = require('fs');
const dir = './dir/path';

readdirSync(dir).forEach(f => rmSync(`${dir}/${f}`));
```

Comment: What if that directory contains also folders ?

Comment: @Lucke Pass `{recursive: true}` to the `rmSync` as second argument.

Comment: This is a nice one-liner, thanks.  For me it failed when a directory was encountered within the folder I was trying to clean the files out of.  Here's what I came up with to fix it:  `readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true }).forEach(f => { if (f.isFile()) rmSync(path.join(dir, f.name)) });`

Answer (score 43):

There is package called rimraf that is very handy. It is the UNIX command rm -rf for node.

Nevertheless, it can be too powerful too because you can delete folders very easily using it. The following commands will delete the files inside the folder. If you remove the *, you will remove the log folder.

```
const rimraf = require('rimraf');
rimraf('./log/*', function () { console.log('done'); });
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf

Comment: IMO, what can be solved with a function, should never be solved with a package.

Comment: @AdityaAnand - what function? it is impossible without importing some package or writing a ton of code by yourself

Comment: @vsync IMO this is not a lot of code: `fs.readdirSync('./log/').forEach(file => fs.rmSync(file, { recursive: true }))`. 

Comment: You are importing `fs`.... and probably also `path` but you just let that out. Of course, those packages are actually importing OS code... which is importing file system code via the drivers etc....

Never write code yourself unless you can do a better job then what is already out there and open source

Answer (score 22):

Building on @Waterscroll's response, if you want to use async and await in node 8+:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);
const unlink = util.promisify(fs.unlink);
const directory = 'test';

async function toRun() {
  try {
    const files = await readdir(directory);
    const unlinkPromises = files.map(filename => unlink(`${directory}/${filename}`));
    return Promise.all(unlinkPromises);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

toRun();
```

Comment: great! Just what i was searching for as i want to keep on specific file in the folder :D

Comment: Just a note that `return await Promise` is redundant. You can just do `return Promise`. The `toRun` function is async, so when a promise is returned, the app can await on that.

Comment: You can now use `const { promises: fs } = require('fs');` from node 10+ i believe.

Answer (score 5):

Short vanilla Node 10 solution

```js
import fs from 'fs/promises'

await fs.readdir('folder').then((f) => Promise.all(f.map(e => fs.unlink(e))))
```

Comment: Don't you want to wait for it? `await Promise.all(files.map(file => fs.promises.unlink(path.join(directory, file))))`

Comment: @c24w Fixed. Thanks

Comment: I think this is like the holy grail I've been looking for. Assuming the following works also:
```fs.promises.readdir('path-to-folder').then((f) => Promise.all(f.map(e => fs.promises.unlink(e))))
.then(()=>{console.log("all deleted")})
```

Comment: @AndreasTzionis each to their own, but I think the mixed promise patterns make this confusing to read, compared to pure `async`/`await`: `const files = await fs.promises.readdir('path-to-folder');` and `await Promise.all(files.map(f => fs.promises.unlink(f)))`. Also, you also seem to have lost the `path.join` from the original answer - not sure if that was intentional. Bonus: you can use `'fs/promises'` to avoid having to put `.promises` on every operation.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another alternative:

```
import {mkdir, rm} from 'fs/promises';

async function clearDirectory(dirPath) {
    await rm(dirPath, {recursive: true});
    await mkdir(dirPath);
}
```

This *is* actually deleting the directory entirely (with `rm`) but then immediately recreating it so it looks like it was merely emptied out. This will affect folder metadata and possibly ownership, so it will not work in all use cases.

Answer (score 4):

How about run a command line:

```
require('child_process').execSync('rm -rf /path/to/directory/*')
```

Comment: This method does not work on all platforms.

Answer (score 4):

You can use node's `fs` module to `rm` a folder along with all of its contents using the `recursive` flag.

```
const fs = require("fs");

function removeFolderContents(dir) {
  fs.rmSync(dir, { recursive: true, force: true });
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Promise version of directory cleanup utility function:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises; // promise version of require('fs');

async function cleanDirectory(directory) {
    try {
        await fs.readdir(directory).then((files) => Promise.all(files.map(file => fs.unlink(`${directory}/${file}`))));
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

cleanDirectory("./somepath/myDir");
```

Answer (score 2):

Improvement on Rodrigo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182416/2579739), using async and promises

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

const directory = 'test';

let files = [];
try{
   files = await fs.readdir(directory);
}
catch(e){
   throw e;
}

if(!files.length){
  return;
}

const promises = files.map(e => fs.unlink(path.join(directory, e)));
await Promise.all(promises)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'filename.js'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: 'filename.js'
}
```

Add the folder path in

```js
const folderPath = './Path/to/folder/'
await fs.promises.readdir(folderPath)
    .then((f) => Promise.all(f.map(e => fs.promises.unlink(`${folderPath}${e}`))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with vanilla nodejs dependencies :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = 'www/foldertoempty';

fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(f=>fs.rmdirSync(

`${dir}/${f}`,
{
recursive : true,
force : true 
}
));
```

Adding recursive and force makes sure that non-empty folders get deleted as well.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner of the accepted answer:

```js
import { join } from 'path';
import { readdir, unlink } from 'fs/promises';

await Promise.all((await readdir(dir)).map((file) => unlink(join(dir, file))));
```

Answer (score 0):

##### ❄️ You can use `graph-fs` [↗️](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graph-fs)

```js
directory.clear() // empties it
```

Comment: For those who who don't know what `graph-fs` is, this answer is good but some what unclear;
[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graph-fs)
Check out the above link for `graph-fs` documentation. This does solve the problem of removing files from a directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
const fsExtra = require('fs-extra')
let dir = "./temp";
await fsExtra.emptyDir(dir);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers here.. This is what I ended up doing, removes all files and folders inside the folder without removing it.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
function emptyDir(path){
    let files = fs.readdirSync(path);
    for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        let file = `${path}/${files[i]}`;
        if(fs.lstatSync(file).isDirectory()){
            fs.rmSync(file, {recursive: true, force: true});
        }else{
            fs.unlinkSync(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const fs = require();

fs.readdir('test', (err, files) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (let file of files) 
        fs.unlink('./test/' + file, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        });

    return fs.rmdir('test', (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('folder is deleted');
    });

});
```