# Is there a way to delete json files produced by protractor cucumber on Jenkins when using protractor flake?

Tags: bash, jenkins, protractor, automated-tests, cucumber

I'm running protractor flake on Jenkins for automation testing using the framework protractor cucumber. Each time the tests run, a json is outputted. Is there a way to delete the old json output or a bash command that can detect if protractor flake is rerun. I have protractor flake set to have 3 attempts. So if protractor flake reruns the 3rd time, I don't want the 1st and 2nd json output from protractor cucumber to be in the folder.

That way the cucumber report won't have flake tests in it.

This is the command I have right now on Jenkins when I do a build:

```
rm -rf e2e/reports
mkdir e2e/reports
npm install
node flake e2e/staging.protractor.conf.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `onCleanup` field/function in the protractor config. I recommend using that to write yourself a function that will delete the files in `/e2e/reports`. You can use the `exitcode` to delete the file if the first or second attempt fails. This will be a little tricky as you will need to find a way to keep track of which iteration you are on so that the report doesn't get deleted if the third run fails also.

See the comments in the [protractor config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/4f74a4ec753c97adfe955fe468a39286a0a55837/lib/config.ts#L501) for more details.

Comment: Perfect! Your comment me made look for a way to delete the files in Javascript. I'm using this to remove all the files on onPrepare() when node flake reruns again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072866/how-to-remove-all-files-from-directory-without-removing-directory-in-node-js/42182416

Comment: Ahh good call. That way you don't have to worry about keeping track of when iteration you are on at all. Very nice.