# How to delete all files and subdirectories in a directory with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am working with node.js and need to empty a folder. I read a lot of deleting files or folders. But I didn't find answers, how to delete all files AND folders in my folder `Test`, without deleting my folder Test` itself.

I try to find a solution with `fs` or `extra-fs`. Happy for some help!

Comment: Well, can you delete all folder and create an empty one?

Comment: That is, what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I think you should take a look here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072866/how-to-remove-all-files-from-directory-without-removing-directory-in-node-js/49125621, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052762/remove-directory-which-is-not-empty?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT 1:** Hey **@Harald**, you should use the **del** library that **@ziishaned** posted above. Because it's much more clean  and scalable. And use my answer to learn how it works under the hood :)

---

**EDIT: 2 (Dec 26 2021):** I didn't know that there is a `fs` method named `fs.rm` that you can use to accomplish the task with just one line of code.

```
fs.rm(path_to_delete, { recursive: true }, callback)
// or use the synchronous version
fs.rmSync(path_to_delete, { recursive: true })
```

The above code is analogous to the linux shell command: `rm -r path_to_delete`.

---

We use `fs.unlink` and `fs.rmdir` to remove files and **empty** directories respectively. To check if a path represents a directory we can use `fs.stat()`.

So we've to list all the contents in your `test` directory and remove them one by one.

By the way, I'll be using the **synchronous** version of `fs` methods mentioned above (e.g., `fs.readdirSync` instead of `fs.readdir`) to make my code simple. But if you're writing a production application then you should use **asynchronous** version of all the fs methods. I leave it up to you to read the docs here [Node.js v14.18.1 File System documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html).

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const DIR_TO_CLEAR = "./trash";

emptyDir(DIR_TO_CLEAR);

function emptyDir(dirPath) {
  const dirContents = fs.readdirSync(dirPath); // List dir content

  for (const fileOrDirPath of dirContents) {
    try {
      // Get Full path
      const fullPath = path.join(dirPath, fileOrDirPath);
      const stat = fs.statSync(fullPath);
      if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        // It's a sub directory
        if (fs.readdirSync(fullPath).length) emptyDir(fullPath);
        // If the dir is not empty then remove it's contents too(recursively)
        fs.rmdirSync(fullPath);
      } else fs.unlinkSync(fullPath); // It's a file
    } catch (ex) {
      console.error(ex.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Feel free to ask me if you don't understand anything in the code above :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [del](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) package to delete   files and folder within a directory recursively without deleting the parent directory:

1. Install the required dependency:

   ```sh
   npm install del
   ```
2. Use below code to delete subdirectories or files within `Test` directory without deleting `Test` directory itself:

   ```js
   const del = require("del");

   del.sync(['Test/**', '!Test']);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require("fs");

// Node fs module "rmdirSync" is deprecated since v16.0.0.
fs.rmdirSync('./del_path', {recursive: true,});

// Node fs module "rmSync" support is starting from v14.14.0.
fs.rmSync('./del_path', {recursive: true, force: true,});

// If you do not want to care about the node version, 
// just use unix command "rm -rf" instead by installing "shelljs" package.
const shell = require("shelljs");
shell.rm('-rf', './del_path');
```

Comment: This deletes a file not a folder

Comment: @user1034912 `fs.rmSync('./del_path', {recursive: true, force: true,})` will delete a folder and every file inside