# How can i remove everything from a folder?

Tags: javascript, directory

i want to remove all of the things of my folder metadata
my attempt is this

```
const folderPath = './metadata/'
await fs.promises.readdir(folderPath)
  .then((f) => Promise.all(f.map(e => fs.promises.unlink(`${folderPath}${e}`))))
```

but i am getting this error:

```
(node:7329) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink './metadata/LP'
```

**BTW: LP is a directory**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all files from directory without removing directory in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072866/how-to-remove-all-files-from-directory-without-removing-directory-in-node-js)

Comment: @lusc with the choised answer i got this error  if (err) throw err;
               ^

[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'metadata/LP] {
  errno: -1,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: 'metadata/LP'
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink './metadata/LP'`

Maybe `./metadata/LP` is a directory. Unlink can delete only files.

Try to use [fs.rmdir()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrmdirpath-options-callback) or [del](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) NPM.

Comment: yep is folder LP